# Python: Process VS Thread. What is the difference when only run 1 progress/thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiple-processes

I knew that Process and Thread are totally different things. But I have a question about them. Since Python has GIL, so is there any performance difference between a single thread and a single process working on a task?

edit 1:
I think there is no different for a task that need huge CPU calculating. But if it is a Asynchronous_I/O task, the the process still have advantage since it could multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post [Sjoerd][[Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python])

Comment: Got it . Thank you.